# "copper in liquid state" or "copper in the liquid state"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Which is correct or more correct? Why?

1. Copper in liquid state
2. Copper in the liquid state

Comment: in a liquid state v. in liquid form. But you might show some research you yourself have done.

Comment: Copper in *its* liquid state, or more usually **molten copper** since its liquid state does not occur naturally.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That's what I thought. But according to [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=water+in+its+liquid+state%2Cwater+in+the+liquid+state&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwater%20in%20its%20liquid%20state%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwater%20in%20the%20liquid%20state%3B%2Cc0), ***the*** is more common than ***its*** (at least for ***water***). Except I'm not sure why "natural state" should make a difference.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica water's solid, liquid and gaseous states all occur naturally, but copper does not have a liquid state unless you melt it.